# Как перезаписывать данные в файл, с функцией fstream?

Tags: c++

Мне надо записывать данные в файл, как в вектор или по блокам а так же считывать их или удалять.

Я знаю что `fstream` может записать данные в файл по порядку, а так же перезаписывать.
Я хочу удалять именно какую то часть данных внутри файла, например у меня есть несколько записей в `file.txt`

```
1 запись A
2 запись B
3 запись V
4 запись C
```

Я хочу удалить `2 запись B` а все остальное оставить, Или я бы хотел перезаписать `1 запись А` и так же все остальное оставить нетронутым.

Могу я так делать?

Или если более простой вариант в `file2.txt` есть обычная нумерация

```
1
2
3
4
```

Нужно удалить или изменять нумерацию, в зависимости какой номер я хочу изменить.
В данном случаи мне нужно изменить `1 и 2` и получаем такой вариант

```
5 // был 1 стал 5
6
3
4
```

код который перезаписывает данные в файл, что сейчас есть у меня.

```
fs.write((char*)&data, sizeof data);
```

код который читает эти данные, в принципе он идентичный.

```
fs.read((char*)&data, sizeof data);
```

Все остальное по стандарту, открыть файл, выполнить `write` или `read` закрыть файл ничего нового.
Как я понимаю нужно именно поменять код `write` и `read` на что то другое.

Так же я думал реализовать через цикл и перезаписывать все данные по новой, но я понимаю, что чем больше будет файл, тем дольше станет цикл.

Comment: Для этого нет никаких встроенных механизмов. Так что да, перезаписывать все данные после точки изменения.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat какой то короткий ответ получилось, может есть библиотеки что бы мне велосипед не делать?

Comment: Почему так трудно грамотно  изложить простой вопрос?